# Using variable lists in ansible returns undefined variable

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook, rhel8

Here is my variable list file vars/blah.yml:

```
---
stuff:
 - stuff1: bill
   stuff2: sue
```

I just trying to get the values of the variable stuff.

Here's my playbook:

```
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - vars/blah.yml
  tasks:

  - name: test
    debug:
      var: "{{ item.stuff1 }} {{ item.stuff2 }}"
    loop :
      - "{{ stuff }}"
```

I'm getting this error.

```
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'stuff1'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/automation/plays/test1.yml': line 11, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: test\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edited the formatting on the variables.
Still getting the same results.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

```yaml
  loop: "{{ stuff }}"
```

## Full story

On the contrary of the former and still widely defaulty used `with_items:`, a bare `loop:` does not apply an automatic `flatten(level=1)` on the passed arguments.

For further info about this feature, you can see:

- [the item lookup documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/items_lookup.html)
- [the `with_items` to `loop` migration procedure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items) on the ansible loops documentation.

If your example was using `with_items`

```yaml
  with_items: 
    - "{{ stuff }}"
```

the resulting list would still be exactly the one you defined in your file.

Now used with `loop`

```yaml
  loop:
    - "{{ stuff }}"
```

you are looping over a list of lists which looks like (note the solo dash on top of the below example and the indentation of the rest of the content: it's not a typo).

```yaml
- 
  - stuff1: bill
    stuff2: sue
```

So the first element you get in your loop is actually your full list in your var file.

To fix that, just pass the variable correctly to `loop`, i.e.

```yaml
  loop: "{{ stuff }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your variable file is wrong. The top level is not a list, it should look like this:

```
---
stuff:
  - stuff1: bill
    stuff2: sue
```

Additionally, the path to the vars file should start with a / from the Ansible root:

```
vars_files:
  - /vars/blah.yml
```

Comment: Changed the formatting and same error.